# Xcode error: The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

When using Xcode 13.2.1 and SwiftUI to implement a simple slideshow, I am hitting a compile-time error in which Xcode takes about 5 minutes on my M1 to decide it cannot parse my code, and eventually gives me the error:

> The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable
> time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions

I narrowed it down to the NavigationLink line near the bottom. If I comment that out, it compiles quickly with only a warning.

The following is my Minimal, Reproducible Example:

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

enum MarkerType: Double {
    case unlabeled = -99
    case end = -4
    case start  = -3
    case stop = -2
    case blank = -1
    case image = 1
}

class LabeledImage {
    let image: Image
    let marker: Double
    var appeared = false
    
    init(image: Image, marker: Double) {
        self.image = image
        self.marker = marker
    }
}

struct SlideShow {
    private let maxImages: Int = 10000
    var images = [LabeledImage]()
    var labels = [String]()
    var totalImages: Int { return self.images.count }
    private var fromFolder: URL
    
    init(fromURL: URL = Bundle.main.bundleURL.appendingPathComponent("Contents/Resources/DefaultImages")) {
        self.fromFolder = fromURL
    }
}

class AppState: ObservableObject {
    static var docDir: URL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    @Published var isMainMenuActive = false
    @Published var loadFolder: URL = Bundle.main.bundleURL.appendingPathComponent("Contents/Resources/DefaultImages")
    @Published var intervalSeconds: Double = 0.6

    var saveFolder = URL(fileURLWithPath: "BCILab", relativeTo: docDir)
    var labels = [String]()
    var totalImages: Int = 0
    var saveIndex: Int = 0
}


struct minsample: View {
    @StateObject private var appState = AppState()
    @State private var slideshow = SlideShow()
    @State private var selection: Int = 0
    
    private func insertAppears(_ marker: Double) {
        let nmarker = marker + 100.0
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ForEach(0..<slideshow.images.count-1, id: \.self) { i in
                let thisImage = slideshow.images[i].image
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .onAppear(perform: { insertAppears(slideshow.images[i].marker) })
                let nextImage = slideshow.images[i+1].image
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .onAppear(perform: { insertAppears(slideshow.images[i+1].marker) })

                NavigationLink(destination: nextImage, tag: i, selection: self.$selection) { thisImage }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Image` is not a `View` so you can't pass it as argument for `destination:`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson -- assuming that it's `SwiftUI.Image` and not something defined elsewhere with the same name, it is a valid `View` and destination.

Comment: @jnpdx that is of course a possibility

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, using an index-based solution in `ForEach` is a bad idea. It breaks SwiftUI's system for diffing the views and tends to lead to compile-time issues as well.

I'd start by making `LabeledImage` `Identifiable`:

```
class LabeledImage : Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    let image: Image
    let marker: Double
    var appeared = false
    
    init(image: Image, marker: Double) {
        self.image = image
        self.marker = marker
    }
}
```

*(I'd also make it a `struct` -- more on that later)*

Then, since you do need indexes to achieve your `nextImage` functionality, you can use `.enumerated` on the collection:

```
struct MinSample: View {
    @StateObject private var appState = AppState()
    @State private var slideshow = SlideShow()
    @State private var selection: Int? = 0
    
    private func insertAppears(_ marker: Double) {
        let nmarker = marker + 100.0
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ForEach(Array(slideshow.images.enumerated()), id: \.1.id) { (index,imageModel) in
                if index < slideshow.images.count - 1 {
                    let thisImage = imageModel.image
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .onAppear(perform: { insertAppears(imageModel.marker) })
                    let nextImage = slideshow.images[index + 1].image
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .onAppear(perform: { insertAppears(slideshow.images[index+1].marker) })

                    NavigationLink(destination: nextImage, tag: index, selection: self.$selection) { thisImage }
                } else {
                    EmptyView()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above compiles quickly on my M1 with no issues.

---

Now, not directly-related to your issue, but there are some other things I would change:

1. Make your models `struct`s, which SwiftUI generally deals with much better when doing state comparisons
2. Don't store references to SwiftUI `Image`s -- instead, store a reference to a path or some other way to recreate that image. That will make the transition for `LabeledImage` to a `struct` easier anyway. So, your model might look like this:

```
struct LabeledImage : Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    let imageName: String
    let marker: Double
    var appeared = false
}
```

3. Consider whether or not you need the `tag` and `selection` parameters in your `NavigationLink` -- perhaps it's just not clear in the minimal example why they're used.

Comment: Thanks! I will try to combine all your suggestions into a refactored SlideShow that doesn't use ForEach. I was trying to use onAppear() within TabView to sync the display of an image with writing a marker to a file, but it seems to only fire when the image is navigated to, and was firing at odd times following a reload of the images.

Comment: You don't need to not use `ForEach` -- you just don't want to use it with only indexes to identify the items.

Comment: To piggy-pack on @jnpdx's comments, you have a class/struct named `LabeledImage`, yet it contains no property for the label. Instead, you have a separate array to hold the labels. I think you'd be better off adding `var label: String` to it and then it will be easier to access the label, because you won't have to keep track of indices and keep your arrays in sync.

Comment: @jnpdx after suggesting the OP make `LabeledImage` identifiable, you still used `id` in the `ForEach`, but that shouldn't be necessary, right?

Comment: @Zonker.in.Geneva because I'm using `enumerated` and the `id` is on the second element of the resulting tuple, explicitly using the keypath to the `id` is still necessary.